# Mac High Sierra JAVA_HOME

Tags: java-home, macos-high-sierra

I'm running High Sierra, have Java9 installed, but need to default to jdk1.8.

I added the following line to ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc, both individually and at the same time.

`export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home"`

When I open a new terminal "java -version" would show java9, and "echo $JAVA_HOME" prints nothing.

Finally I just deleted Java9, but can you still specify a default java version or does it just default to the latest version no matter what?